# PHP foreach causing "white page" in Yii Framework, loading styles from DB

Tags: php, yii, foreach

I am loading my stylesheets from my DB, kind my own interesting attempt at building a CMS. Anyways I am currently doing this by calling the styles in the head section of my main.php in my layout. This is the Yii framework btw. It's very strange because this worked for about 10 hours and then all of a sudden stopped being accepted. I am thinking it may be a bad value in the database that is throwing the stylesheets off but they all seem to load correctly when i preview the html. Here is my code;

I have narrowed it down to this line is somehow causing the error (which php will not report on) but I can't figure out why:

```
     echo $valueStrip.":".$cssAttrib->$value2.";";
```

here is the rest of the code so you can make sense of it:

```
$sql = 'Select selector from tbl_css t';

$css= Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
$cssCols = new Css;
$cssColsAr = $cssCols->attributeLabels('');

foreach($css as $key => $value)
{

    foreach($cssColsAr as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        $cssAttrib = Css::model()->find('selector=:selector', 
                                  array(':selector'=>$value['selector']));
        $valueStrip = $value2;
        $valueStrip = str_replace('_','-',$value2);
        if ($valueStrip == 'id')
        {
            $value2 = 'color';
        }
        if ($valueStrip == 'selector')
        {
            $value2 = 'color';
        }
        echo "<style>";
        echo $value['selector']."{";
        echo $valueStrip.":".$cssAttrib->$value2.";";
        echo "}</style>";
    } 
}
```

here's an example of the generated styles:

```
<style>body{color:white;}</style>
<style>body{margin:0 px auto;}</style>
```

etc... I see no reason for it to crash?

error logs for apache:

```
[Sun May 05 14:53:45.529008 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4768:tid 412] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.2\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2'
[Sun May 05 14:53:45.529008 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4768:tid 412] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1248
[Sun May 05 14:53:46.059409 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1248:tid 288] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun May 05 14:59:38.304126 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 796] [client 127.0.0.1:49410] PHP Warning:  require_once(C:\\wamp\\www\\blog/../../framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\\wamp\\www\\blog\\index.php on line 10
[Sun May 05 14:59:38.304126 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 796] [client 127.0.0.1:49410] PHP Stack trace:
[Sun May 05 14:59:38.304126 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 796] [client 127.0.0.1:49410] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\blog\\index.php:0
[Sun May 05 14:59:38.304126 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 796] [client 127.0.0.1:49410] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\\wamp\\www\\blog/../../framework/yii.php' (include_path='.;C:\\php\\pear') in C:\\wamp\\www\\blog\\index.php on line 10
[Sun May 05 14:59:38.304126 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 796] [client 127.0.0.1:49410] PHP Stack trace:
[Sun May 05 14:59:38.304126 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 796] [client 127.0.0.1:49410] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\blog\\index.php:0
[Sun May 05 15:07:03.154570 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 788] [client 127.0.0.1:49423] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ')' in C:\\wamp\\www\\tblog\\protected\\config\\main.php on line 62
[Sun May 05 15:07:03.154570 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 788] [client 127.0.0.1:49423] PHP Stack trace:
[Sun May 05 15:07:03.154570 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 788] [client 127.0.0.1:49423] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\tblog\\index.php:0
[Sun May 05 15:07:03.154570 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 788] [client 127.0.0.1:49423] PHP   2. YiiBase::createWebApplication() C:\\wamp\\www\\tblog\\index.php:13
[Sun May 05 15:07:03.154570 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 788] [client 127.0.0.1:49423] PHP   3. YiiBase::createApplication() C:\\wamp\\www\\yii\\framework\\YiiBase.php:98
[Sun May 05 15:07:03.154570 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 788] [client 127.0.0.1:49423] PHP   4. CApplication->__construct() C:\\wamp\\www\\yii\\framework\\YiiBase.php:125
```

php error log is blank

Comment: Do you have access to your error logs on the server?

Comment: Have you checked the source of the "white page"? You won't see the error in the browser, if it's in a style tag - I had that several times ;)

Comment: attached my apache server error logs, php error log is blank, interesting you think it could be a style error, is there a limit to inline style sheets, there are currently about 840 sheets generated with one style per sheet. Also strange as this *was* working correctly before I added a new style to be generated in the DB, I have since deleted that style...

Comment: If you see an blank page, it could be because you are not displaying errors & an exception has been thrown. I.e it is running in production mode. Make sure display errors are on & you are running in development mode - then you can debug from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look carefully at your apache logs :

```
[Sun May 05 15:07:03.154570 2013] [:error] [pid 1248:tid 788] [client 127.0.0.1:49423] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ')' in C:\\wamp\\www\\tblog\\protected\\config\\main.php on line 62
```

You should simply correct this syntax error in `C:\wamp\www\tblog\protected\config\main.php` on line 62.

Comment: wow I can't believe I blew by that. I will try it when I get home thanks for taking the time soju. I think I was getting frustrated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the actual problem was a bad value in my Css model for opacity. Apparently 1.0 isn't accepted. I guess I will have to incorporate some validation for my CSS model based on proper rules for each property when I get the chance. I am still going to accept soju's answer, as proper error checking is a must! Thanks all!